# Non-abelian averaging trick

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

It is well-known that in representation theory of finite abelian groups, one can consider the averaging trick as follows.

If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of a finite abelian group $G$, then for any $g\in G$, $\prod_i \sigma^i(g)$ is fixed by $\sigma$.

Is there any way to do the averaging trick for finite non-abelian groups to produce an element fixed by $\sigma$? (I suppose one can potentially further average all possible results or construct something like commutators?)

Comment: It can be natural to consider only the $\sigma_i(g)$ that map to the center of the group in the product.